# How to take screenshot of a specific url using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, url

I need to take screenshot of a power BI report using python, I want to pass Power BI URL. That URL will have flow like this -> **email -> submit**, then **password -> SignIn** then **stay SignIn -> yes**
I have tried below code. I have to run this script in databricks, this will be automated which will run on a particular time everyday

```
import datetime
import time
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


def login_powerbi(username, password):
    # Set up the ChromeDriver path in the PATH environment variable
    chromedriver_path = 'C:/Users/Desktop/chrome_driver/chromedriver.exe'
    os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + chromedriver_path

    # Set up the webdriver
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()

    try:
        # Open the Power BI report URL (login page)
        driver.get("https://your_powerbi_url_here")

        # Wait for the login page to load
        wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
        email_field = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "email")))
        email_field.send_keys(username)

        # Submit the email form
        email_form = driver.find_element_by_id("i0116")
        email_form.submit()

        # Wait for the password field to load and then enter the password
        password_field = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "i0118"))) #i0118
        password_field.send_keys(password)

        # Submit the password form
        password_form = driver.find_element_by_id("i0118") #idSIButton9
        password_form.submit()

        # Wait for the "Stay signed in?" prompt to load and then click "Yes"
        stay_signed_in_prompt = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "idSIButton9"))) #idSIButton9
        stay_signed_in_prompt.click()

        # Wait for the Power BI report to load after authentication
        driver.implicitly_wait(30)

        # Add a delay before taking the screenshot to ensure the report is fully loaded
        time.sleep(10)

        # Take the screenshot
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        file_name = f'screenshot_{now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S")}.png'
        output_path = "C:/Users/Desktop/Screenshot/output/"

        screenshot_output_file = f'{output_path}/{file_name}'
        driver.save_screenshot(screenshot_output_file)

        print(f"Screenshot saved as {screenshot_output_file}")

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error during login and screenshot capture: {e}")

    finally:
        # Close the browser
        driver.quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Replace 'your_username' and 'your_password' with your actual Power BI login credentials
    login_powerbi("your_username", "your_password")
```

But the above code is giving below error, what could be the possible solution

```
Error during login and screenshot capture: Message: element not interactable
  (Session info: chrome=115.0.5790.110)
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
        GetHandleVerifier [0x0063A813+48355]
        (No symbol) [0x005CC4B1]
        (No symbol) [0x004D5220]
        (No symbol) [0x004FD046]
        (No symbol) [0x004FC8B1]
        (No symbol) [0x0051A73C]
        (No symbol) [0x004F9A36]
        (No symbol) [0x0051AA94]
        (No symbol) [0x0052C922]
        (No symbol) [0x0051A536]
        (No symbol) [0x004F82DC]
        (No symbol) [0x004F93DD]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x0089AABD+2539405]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x008DA78F+2800735]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x008D456C+2775612]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x006C51E0+616112]
        (No symbol) [0x005D5F8C]
        (No symbol) [0x005D2328]
        (No symbol) [0x005D240B]
        (No symbol) [0x005C4FF7]
        (No symbol) [0x76FE00C9]
        RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77587B1E+286]
        RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77587AEE+238]

[ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(980)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -3
```

Comment: your code reach the line to save screenshot??

Comment: Nope, from the email itself it throws error.

Comment: Can you not to try catch and show, on which line does it fail?

Comment: @Yaroslavm I tried on this line -> password_field = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "i0118"))) ->  getting this error -> Error during login and screenshot capture: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_id'

Comment: I have no idea what a "Power BI" is but if the only API it provides is a web form I would give serious consideration to replacing it with a saner product that exposes an API more appropriate for automation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happened, because your input is not rendered, but exist in DOM after clicking on submit field.

Try this approach with password field:

```js
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
email_field = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "email")))

email_field.send_keys("some-email")
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[type=submit]").click()

password_field = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[type=password]")))
password_field.send_keys('some-password')
```

Comment: Getting this error now -> Message: element not interactable: [object HTMLInputElement] has no size and location
  (Session info: chrome=115.0.5790.110)
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
        GetHandleVerifier [0x0063A813+48355]

Comment: @gourav let's try to search by visibility, try updated code

Comment: @gourav if we are talking about PowerBI Microsoft service, I was able to type email in password with code above.

Comment: I got the above error after using updated code, and here is the HTML structure -><div class="emailDetailArea"><div class="emailDetailContent"><div class="emailDetailContentArea"><div class="emailContentInput"><div class="emailInputTitle">Email</div><div><input class="pbi-text-input" type="text" placeholder="Enter email" id="email"></div></div></div><button class="pbi-fluent-button primary" id="submitBtn" onclick="submitEmail()">Submit</button></div></div>

Comment: Have you tried latest version?)

Comment: Please have a look on the above HTML structure

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254803/discussion-between-yaroslavm-and-gourav).